# Visual Studio tableadapter configuration wizard failing to parse mysql statement

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I have a MySQL statement which when executed in MySQL workbench, successfully returns a result. The statement in question is below:

```
SELECT report.*, client.`Client`, 3rdpartyreport.`Status` FROM report
LEFT JOIN client ON report.ClientID = client.ID 
LEFT JOIN 3rdpartyreport ON (report.`Serial No` = 3rdpartyreport.`Serial No` AND report.`AssignedTo` = 3rdpartyreport.`Received By`) 
WHERE (report.Status <> 'Deleted') 
ORDER BY report.`Serial No` DESC
```

I am joining a column from the client table and the 3rdparty table to the report table. However, when I input this exact query into Visual Studio 2013 Dataset designer, it gives the error:

```
Error in join expression. Unable to parse query text.
```

As soon as I remove one of the LEFT JOIN lines, it works ok. Why doesn't Visual Studio allow multiple left joins? Am I doing something wrong, and if not then is there another way I can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to have 3rdpartyreport written as '3rdpartyreport', because it starts with a digit. Workbench doesn't need this apparently.